# Can I customize the search in QComboBox?

Tags: qt, search, combobox

In a non-editable QComboBox, if you press some keys quickly, a search will be performed in the displayed texts and the first item which has the prefix you typed will be selected. For example, if there are six items in the combobox, "Alabama", "Alaska", "California", "Colorado", "Ohio" and "Louisiana", and you press C, "California" will be selected. If you wait some time and press O, "Ohio" will be selected. However, if you quickly type "CO", "Colorado" will be selected.

Is this behaviour a Qt's feature? Apparently, this works universally, in spite of the GUI framework underneath. If it is Qt that handles this, can I customize it? What I want to do is basically perform the search based in data that is not displayed in the ComboBox. For example, in a ComboBox to select users, in which the logins are listed, it would suffice to type the user's last name to select it. It would be enough to search for matches in the middle of the text, though (for example, typing "nia" to select "California").

At first, QCompleter seemed to help, but it looks like it would only be useful in an editable QComboBox...

If this is not possible with QComboBox, which widget should be used to achieve this?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subclass `QComboBox` and reimplement the [`keyPressEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#keyPressEvent) . Let's assume that in your combo box you have implemented a function that adds an entry with two arguments: the login name and the actual name:

```
void MyComboBox::addEntry(QString loginName, QString name)
{
    addItem(loginName);
    // Store the name in a member variable, eg a map between names and login names
    namesMap.insert(name, loginName);
}

void MyComboBox::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *evt)
{
    QString currentString = ebt->text();
    if (currentString.isEmpty())
    {
        QComboBox::keyPressEvent(evt);
        return; 
    } 

    // Iterate through the map and search for the given name
    QMapIterator<QString, QString> it(namesMap);
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
         it.next();
         QString name = it.key();
         if (name.contains(currentString))
         {
             // it.value() is the login name corresponding to the name
             // we have to find its index in the combo box in order to select it 
             int itemIndex = findText(it.value());
             if (itemIndex >= 0)
                 setCurrentIndex(itemIndex);
             return;
         }  
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's simple to implement. The problem I imagined before was that I thought a KeyEvent would only send the last pressed key, so I would have to keep the last time an event was handled to decide whether to start a new search or continue the last one. From your answer, I understand the event will have the complete typed text when the interval between keystrokes is short enough. Is this right?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to keep the timestamp of the event and build the string incrementally. But this is not that hard to implement.

Comment: No, it's not. I was just trying to avoid reinventig the wheel, if it already existed, but I will do as you suggested. Thanks :)